# Grab Preexisting google.maps.places.Autocomplete Object

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have two major scripts on one page.  One is site-wide and implements Google Autocomplete on each `$("input.input-location")` on the site.  The other is only on the search page.  I need to use the `getPlace()` method of the Autocomplete object in the second script.  They are segmented well, and do not take up any global variables, which in this case poses a problem.  I can't grab the original object from a specific location input.  I cannot easily change the site-wide script, though I will if I have to.  And I cannot just change the class of the specific object because a) I'd have to also change/add-to the CSS and b) I'd have to rewrite all the options and restrictions that I want to keep consistent site-wide.

If I make a new Autocomplete object, then the second object has the correct `getPlace()` and the first object's `getPlace()` method returns undefined.  In the first script, I use the place to determine whether or not I should change the input value to the first `PAC` value.  If I change the input value, then neither one has the correct `getPlace()` output.

**So I don't want to make a new Autocomplete object.  How do I grab the first Autocomplete object with only access to the DOM input element?**

Before you ask, yes I have been searching for the answer to this.  Answers to other questions come up instead, like [Google Places Autocomplete API Multiple Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122175/google-places-autocomplete-api-multiple-instances), where their problem is the exact opposite: they have multiple inputs and they want separate objects and end up referencing the first object on accident.  I also cannot find the solution to this in Google's API documentation.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this, I would like to know why?  What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround:**

`$("#searchForm").off("submit");` This removes the eventHandler I had added to the parent form of each location input.

Then I make a new Google Autocomplete Object on the location input.

Then I rewrite the original functionality, which ended up needing custom stuff anyways.

Again, this was just a workaround.  I still end up with two objects.  I just no longer have the first object messing with stuff.  I would still like a real answer to this.